# Type inference in kotlin lambda function not working

Tags: kotlin

My lambda:

```
val streetNumber: Int = {
        num: Int -> num / 4
}
```

How come I am getting this error:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is (Int) -> Int but Int was expected
val streetNumber: Int = {
                        ^
```

My knowledge of my code block is:

1. The first `Int` means I am returning an `Int` type.
2. The 2nd `Int` means I've declared the type of `num` to be `Int`.

Are any of those statements wrong?

Comment: You're declaring `streetNumber` to have type `Int`, but your lambda is of type `(Int) -> Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable type `Int` is not correct in this case, what you want to do instead:

```
val streetNumber: (Int) -> Int = {
    num: Int -> num / 4
}
```

Comment: You do not need `num : Int` inside the lambda, the type is specified on the left side of `=`. It is enough to say `{ num -> num / 4}`. You may do it even shorter if you use the default parameter name - `it`:`:
```
val streetNumber: (Int) -> Int = { it / 4 }
```

Comment: It's optional, yes. In this case, I just fixed the original code and did not simplify it

Answer (score 0):

Declaring:

```
val streetNumber: Int
```

means that `streetNumber`'s data type is `Int` and **not** that the return type is `Int`.
So this conflicts with the assignment:

```
val streetNumber = { num: Int -> num / 4 }
```

In these cases trust the inferred data type which is `(Int) -> Int`
The variable `streetNumber` is not a variable referencing an integer value, 
like for example: `val x: Int = 0`. 
It is a variable referencing a [Lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) which returns an integer value.
You can use it like this:

```
val streetNumber = { num: Int -> num / 4 }
val x: Int = streetNumber(12)
println(x)
```

which will print

```
3
```

Comment: Doesn't the data type have to be the same as the return type? How can you set `Int` as the data type of `streetNumber` and then return a `String` in the function?

Comment: *Doesn't the data type have to be the same as the return type?* No. *How can you set `Int` as the data type of streetNumber*? you don't. The variable `streetNumber`'s data type is  `(Int) -> Int` and not `Int`. Think of it as a function variable. The return type is `Int`.

Comment: To expand on the last comment: `streetNumber` is being set to a *lambda* — an anonymous block of code which takes an `Int` parameter and returns an `Int` (that's what `(Int) -> Int` means).  The code as shown does not *call* the lambda, merely stores it for future use.  If/when it does get called, it will return an `Int`, but that's not what `streetNumber` is being set to.

Comment: Can you give an example where the data type and the return type are different? @forpas

Comment: See my edited answer and check the link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily like,

```
val streetNumber= {
    num: Int -> num / 4
}
```

then, call it like,

```
val number=40
println(div(number))
```

this is the simplest way, to do this thing.